# Unmatching type when passing in the route dictionary an element to a controller despite being equivalent

Tags: c#, razor, controller, parameter-passing

here is a problem I meet where I didn't expect.

I have a

```
class SuperModel {
// many properties.
    public IList<product> listeProduct{ get; set; }
}
```

I construct it, and assign values to every property.

then I pass it into my ActionResult to find everything I need in my razor/Html page here (at the top) :

```
@model SparksWebSite.Models.SuperModel
```

In the same page I call a partial view here :

```
<div class="customDiv">MAIN CONTENT AREA @{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Products/Index.cshtml", Model.listeProduct);}</div>
```

note that the Model.listeProduct represents the SuperModel's property:

```
 public IList<product> listeProduct{ get; set; }
```

And finally in the Action result :

```
public ActionResult Index(List<product> list)
{
    return View(list);
}
```

but the code stops because it says that I am passing in the dictionary an object of type SuperModel, and expect a List ...
So I am pretty stuck here because I don't know how to pass just the properties I want of my superModel class in every partial view I have.

I though razor would interpret like this:

List listeP = SuperModel.listeProduct

What should I do ?

Comment: Why are you sending a list you received from a controller to another controller.  That seems to be a huge [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).. as in.. what logic is the next controller going to do that the original controller didn't handle to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

You are callling Partial View to be rendered using `RenderPartial` while you are expecting the action method to be called and in result the partial view to be returned.

For that you will need to call `RenderAction` method which would call the action method like:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("Index","Controller name",new { list = Model.listeProduct});}
```

or you can also try using `Html.Action` method like:

```
@Html.Action("Index","Controller name",new { list = Model.listeProduct})
```

Comment: Bonjour ! thank you, but it`s ok, I 've founded. I just had to had toList()